# How to split a string list into multiple lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, strsplit

I have the following list:

```
x=['2 5 6 7', '9 11 13 15', '31 52 56 94']
```

My ultimate goal is to display it as table with columns and rows in jupyter notebook.

This is what I have done so far:

1. I converted the list into list of lists and now I have list looking like this:

   `x=[['2 5 6 7'], ['9 11 13 15'], ['31 52 56 94']]`
2. The problem is that I am stuck how to split each string. For example I want to do get:

   `[['2' '5' '6' '7'], ['9' '11' '13' '15'], ['31' '52' '56' '94']]`

so that I can use the following to print a table using pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame (x,columns=['int1','int2','int3','int4'])
print (df)
```

final output should look like this with columns names and row names

```
int1 int2 int3 int4
   2    5    6    7
   9   11   13   15
  31   52   56   94
```

Please help me go in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
x=['2 5 6 7', '9 11 13 15', '31 52 56 94']
pd.DataFrame([s.split() for s in x], columns=['int1', 'int2', 'int3', 'int4'])
```

It gives:

```
  int1 int2 int3 int4
0    2    5    6    7
1    9   11   13   15
2   31   52   56   94
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been stuck on this from last 3 hours.